# Postman - Creating variable from response value

Tags: python, json, api, testing, postman

Maybe as most of you I want to make my work easier :)

Problem: I wonder if it is possible to create a variable in Postman, based on the value made by the response from my application backend.

Description: My application generates objects for the database in POST request, they are based on the data entered on the form - the simplest type of form!:

```
Form data:
name: John
surname: Smith

request: POST /apiUser/create
Body/raw:
name=John&surname=Smith
```

after adding object, backend is generating ID for this object. In Postman I see it in Body, like this:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "id": 4882
    }
}
```

Question: is it possible to create a variable from the ID of the object? The variable must store the value from ID generated by response to request /apiUser/create and then I will create new request /apiUserImage/uploadImg which - thanks to above variable - will cotain ID number generated by /apiUser/create request in Body > form-data.

Or maybe there are som Python programs which handle this?

Why: I need to do a test of uploading user photos, but for this I need to create a new query in postman:

1. POST - / apiUser / create
2. POST - / apiUserImage / uploadImg

Answer (score -2):

You can manually create a variable in postman and assign it value as the id you get in response. Here are the steps to create and use a variable:

1. Select the environment [image]  at the top right of Postman.
2. Next to Globals, select Edit.
3. Add a variable named `my_variable` and give it an initial value of `anythingYouWant`.
4. Select *Save* [image: Save icon] , then close the environment tab.
5. Open a new request tab and enter
   [https://postman-echo.com/get?var=**{{my_variable}}*](https://postman-echo.com/get?var=**%7B%7Bmy_variable%7D%7D*)* as the URL. Hover
   over the variable name to inspect the variable's value and scope.

Comment: can you please tell me where in Postman I can find it?

Comment: @MariaKazik Did it solve your problem? If yes, can you accept the answer?

Comment: I'm sorry but unfortunately not. My question is about executing queries on a chain; so that the value generated by Body in the first response would be substituted to the second request.

Comment: @MariaKazik please refer to this site: https://blog.postman.com/how-to-make-money-using-postman-chaining-requests/